# How to do spin animation like wheel with onSwipe event in flutter?

Tags: animation, flutter, dart

I have an image of wheel and trying to add spin animation on it with onSwipe event.
actually what I did..
I used AnimatedBuider class but image is spinning on initially.

Here the image

```
AnimatedBuilder(
  animation: animationController,
  child: Container(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage("assets/wheel.png", ),
        fit: BoxFit.contain,
      ),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(210.0)),
    ), 
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/2.3,
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/1,
  ),
  builder: (BuildContext context, Widget _widget) {
      return new Transform.rotate(
        angle: animationController.value * 6.3,
        child: _widget,
      );
    },
  ),
```

Animation controller

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  animationController = new AnimationController(
    vsync: this,
    duration: new Duration(seconds: 7),
  );
  animationController.repeat();
}
```

Comment: so do not call `animationController.repeat();`

Comment: I removed it but still spinning initially, I want to call from onSwipe event.

Comment: no, if animation is not started, `AnimatedBuilder` will not be animated

Comment: so, which widget, I use for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution from [flutter_spinning_wheel package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_spinning_wheel#-readme-tab-)